# Solving a 5x5 Magic Square

Tags: magic-square

Is there any strategy involved in solving a 5x5 magic square like this? The array above the square are all the missing values.

[image: 5x5 Magic Square and Missing Numbers Bank]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844897/magic-square-of-numbers and https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=magic+square